# Displaying rows based on a 'category' field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table where i am querying all fields. That part works well. However, it is not displaying the desired output. I am tyring to get the rows to display a different category. In other words, avoid the same category being shown back to back. I have tried using `DISTINCT` but it made no effect. Is there away to base the display based on `category`. How can I achieve the below output? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87b6f/3)

Desired Output

```
game_id game_name                   category
------- --------------------------- --------
634266  street fighter v            fighting
684244  minecraft                   adventure
779343  call of duty modern warfare fps
858168  need for speed - rivals     racing
819837  mortal kombat x             fighting
983565  assassin's creed syndicate  adventure
840832  counter-strike              fps
858768  gran turismo                racing
```

Current Output

```
game_id game_name                   category
------- --------------------------- --------
634266  street fighter v            fighting
684244  minecraft                   adventure
779343  call of duty modern warfare fps
819837  mortal kombat x             fighting
840832  counter-strike              fps
858168  need for speed - rivals     racing
858768  gran turismo                racing
983565  assassin's creed syndicate  adventure
```

Comment: . . You should clarify in the question that you want to cycle through the categories.  Otherwise, it is hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you want each category to appear once and then cycle through them.  Here is an approach.  Enumerate the categories and then sort by the enumeration:

```
select vg.game_id, vg.game_name, vg.category
from (select vg.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = vg.category, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := vg.category, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from videogames vg cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by vg.category, vg.game_id
     ) vg
order by rn,
      field(category, 'fighting', 'adventure', 'fps', 'racing');
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87b6f/6).

Comment: Great, if I have lets say 50 categories? should I add any additional fields to simplify this  query?

Comment: @MaryCoding . . . The only issue with 50 categories is the final sort.  I you are happy with them in alphabetical order, then you can leave out the `field()` and just use `category`.